# Adyen - checkout.create is not a function - Jquery C#

Tags: jquery, payment, adyen

I am trying to implement session (5.0.0) in Adyen but the AdyenCheckout doesn't seems to be getting created.

At "const checkout" variable i get this.

[image]

I am not trying to use "await" as per the adyne documents.

Any workaround? Here is my try.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: sessionDataUrl,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data) {
    try {
      const configuration = {
        clientKey,
        locale: "en_US",
        environment: "test",
        session: {
          id: data.id,
          sessionData: data.sessionObject
        },
        showPayButton: true,
        paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
          ideal: {
            showImage: true,
          },
          card: {
            hasHolderName: true,
            holderNameRequired: true,
            name: "Credit or debit card",
          },
        },
        onSubmit: (state, component) => {
          if (state.isValid) {}
        },
        onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
          console.info("onPaymentCompleted");
          console.info(result, component);
        },
        onError: (error, component) => {
          console.error("onError");
          console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
        },
        onAdditionalDetails: (state, component) => {

        },
      };
      
      const checkout = new AdyenCheckout(configuration);
      const cardComponent = checkout.create('card').mount(document.getElementById('card'));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: ***What*** is returned as undefined? We need much more information here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : added more information as i am getting in return when trying to create adyencheckout object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because AdyenCheckout is supposed to return you a promise?
Is there a specific reason you are trying to avoid promise?

Besides, why are you calling `new`? It is not a constructor..but it still does return an initialized Checkout

Looking at their [source-code](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-web/blob/master/packages/lib/src/index.ts), they are calling something like:

```
async function AdyenCheckout(props) {
  const checkout = new Checkout(props);
  return await checkout.initialize();
}
```

In any case, try this:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    try {
      const configuration = {
       ...
      };
      
      AdyenCheckout(configuration)
        .then((checkout) => {
          checkout.create('card').mount(document.getElementById('card'));
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. They have some strange implementation. Some classes they have not kept default constructor so JSON.stringify throws error as it looks for default constructor of the class.

Comment: I did try your suggestion and it works to an extent and i get the card component injected  but then i get error at the On error event as "Call to https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/v1/sessions/CSBE3764DD8AA0FE1A/setup?clientKey=test_XYZ failed. Error= NETWORK_ERROR: Service at https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/v1/sessions/CSBE3764DD8AA0FE1A/setup?clientKey=test_XYZ is not available"

Comment: And about "new" , it was my mistake. I was looking at the early version of adyen ( before 5.0.0)

Comment: your errors seems to me more like your test environment is not setup properly in adyen admin panel. You should check

Comment: and shouldn't your checkout url be like: `....adyen.com.../v68/sessions/…` ?

Comment: same would go for `paymentMethods`, because I think you are using deprecated version?

Comment: if all else fail, you should log into your adyen dashboard, goto developers -> api urls and double check that your endpoints are correct

Comment: and since original question is answered, it would be really cool if you could accept this answer :D

Comment: Of course... :-) done... and i am using js file as per their document.

Comment: <script src="https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.0.0/adyen.js"

   integrity="sha384-kcKKvS6qZbXycrUw31OJ2/2Hz8A8FTsV9anjvpyQc/IWR1SmkFUw7w7F/t5S3qtA"

   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: yes, however your are using `sessionDataUrl`, which is most probably going to your backend, that is in turn calling adyen service? or maybe you are directly calling adyen session endpoint?
In any case, the error that you sent here, it shows that you are using `v1` instead of their `v68`. If it is handled by nuget package, then you should probably try to upgrade it? Their latest library for .net is 8.0.1

Comment: You can see the implementation for their session here: https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-dotnet-api-library/blob/develop/Adyen/Service/Resource/Checkout/Sessions.cs , which takes the api version from their constants: https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-dotnet-api-library/blob/d4c72791bb0a1cb6efe464698102904e88087e61/Adyen/Constants/ClientConfig.cs

Comment: i am using 8.0.1 and yes, at backend i am calling session checkout as per their example.

Comment: All I can understand now is that your `CheckoutEndpoint` is incorrect. Maybe you are overriding it somewhere?